# Django queryset how to aggregate (ArrayAgg) over queryset with union?

Tags: django, django-queryset, union, aggregate-functions

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

t1= Table1.objects.values('id')
t2= Table2.objects.values('id')
t3= Table3.objects.values('id')

t = t1.union(t2, t3)

t.aggregate(id1=ArrayAgg('id'))
```

**This raises error**

> {ProgramingError} column "__col1" does not exist

**Equivalent raw SQL**

```
SELECT array_agg(a.id) from 
(
    SELECT id FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT id FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM table3
) as a
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate function try to find column **__col1**, but it doesn't exist. So explicitly name the columns with F() objects and use aggregate function:

```
t1= Table1.objects.values(__col1=F('id'))
t2= Table2.objects.values(__col1=F('id'))
t3= Table3.objects.values(__col1=F('id'))

t = t1.union(t2, t3)

t.aggregate(Avg('id'))
```